# How to find the elements in the sub-document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

If I have a data in MongoDB as the following with 2 documents and each document has sub-document of sensors. How can I get the list of **sensors** which the **nodeId** is 1 in MongoDB?

```
{
  "name": "Site 1",
  "sensors": [
    { "nodeId": 1, "value": "23" },
    { "nodeId": 1, "value": "34" },
    { "nodeId": 2, "value": "66" }
  ]
}

{
  "name": "Site 2",
  "sensors": [
    { "nodeId": 2, "value": "78" },
    { "nodeId": 2, "value": "99" },
    { "nodeId": 2, "value": "11" },
    { "nodeId": 1, "value": "45" }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{ 
  "sensors": [
    { "nodeId": 1, "value": "23" },
    { "nodeId": 1, "value": "34" },
    { "nodeId": 1, "value": "45" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation) operator in project as below :

```
db.collectionName.find({"sensors":{"$elemMatch":{"nodeId":1}}},{"sensors.$":1}).pretty()
```

It return only first matching array value because of following limitation of `$` operator

> Since only one array field can appear in the query document, if the array contains documents, to specify criteria on multiple fields of these documents, use the $elemMatch operator.

If you [$aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) then you get your expected result, mongo aggregation query as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$sensors" // first unwind all sensors array 
}, {
  "$match": {
    "sensors.nodeId": 1 //macth your criteria 
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$sensors.nodeId", // group matchinng criteria 
    "sensors": {
      "$push": "$sensors"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "sensors": "$sensors"
  }
}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have a sensors schema and a model(if you're using mongoose):

```
sensors.find({sensors : {'$ne': null }}, function(err, docs){
                if(err)
                    console.log(err);
                else
                    res.end(JSON.stringify({sensors : docs}, null, 3));
});
```